# Arrow with blunted-end head in math mode

Tags: symbols

I want to write some simple gene regulations in math mode in LaTeX. Activation is denoted with a normal arrow, so I can write `$A \rightarrow B$` for A activates B, but I'm failing to find an arrow with a straight-line head for repression. Is there some symbol/package that I can use to write something like `$A \repressionarrow B$` and obtain the following.

[image: repression arrow]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `tikz`, probably a bit overkill

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    regulations/.cd,
    act/.style={-{Stealth}}, % Style for activation
    rep/.style={-{Bar}}, % Style for repression
} 

% Command for regulations (both activation and repression, default activation)
\newcommand{\regulationarrow}[1][act]{%
    \tikz[baseline] {\draw[regulations/#1] (0,0.5ex) --++ (1.5em,0);}%
}

\begin{document}
$a \regulationarrow b$
$A \regulationarrow B$
$a \regulationarrow[act] b$
$A \regulationarrow[act] B$
$a \regulationarrow[rep] b$
$A \regulationarrow[rep] B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find most symbols through [detefixy](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/). There doesn't seem to be something close to what you're looking for, so [BambOo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543957/156238) might be the best way to go.

If you do want to hack something together, you can start with a symbol that looks close to what you want and tweak it a bit. Warning: this may produce some ugly artefacts like lines of the wrong thickness (see e.g. the third example), so this is not really the "correct" solution.

I included a normal arrow for comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} %for intercal
\usepackage{graphics} %for raisebox, rotatebox, and scalebox


\begin{document}
$A \to B$

$A \dashv B$

$A\ \raisebox{.4ex}{\scalebox{1}[.5]{$\dashv$}}\ B$

$A\ \raisebox{-.2ex}{\rotatebox{90}{$\bot$}}\ B$

$A\ \raisebox{-.2ex}{\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{1}[1.2]{$\bot$}}}\ B$

$A\ \raisebox{1.3ex}{\rotatebox{-90}{$\intercal$}}\ B$
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:
[image: Some blunt arrows]