# Can I make a repression arrow ( -| ) in tikz-cd?

Tags: symbols, tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd

[image]

I want to draw a 'repression arrow' that looks like above.
BambOo show how to do this in tikz here: [Arrow with blunted-end head in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543953/arrow-with-blunted-end-head-in-math-mode) 
But how can I do the same thing in tikz-cd?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `-|` to specify the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r,-|] & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, it's amazing. Thanks for your help!